# How to merge/federate two OSGi containers?

Tags: java, osgi, containers, fuseesb

I have FUSE ESB Enterprise installed on two virtual machines.

1. FUSE ESB OSGi container on Virtual Machine vm1, suppose three bundles installed:

   FuseESB:karaf@vm1>osgi:list

   251 A

   252 B

   253 C
2. FUSE ESB OSGi container on Virtual Machine vm2, suppose three bundles installed:
   FuseESB:karaf@vm2>osgi:list

   251 A

   252 B

   253 C

My goal is to combine or federate these two OSGi containers, so that the container on vm1 can see bundle B as well as all the other bundles from vm2. Also the container on vm2 can see bundle A as well as all the other bundles from vm1. That is, one container can access all the bundles from another container.

By access I mean start/stop/update bundles and discover/consume services from another container.

After federation, from vm1:

```
FuseESB:karaf@vm1>osgi:list

251 A

252 B

253 C

254 A'

255 B'

256 C'
```

Because both containers have the same bundle named A, I am wondering if there is some mechanism to automatically rename A to A' to avoid name conflict. 
Is it possible to achieve this goal? Anyone can provide me some information about doing this?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to achieve. This is too vague.

Comment: @NeilBartlett please see the details.

Comment: What do you mean by "one container can access all the bundles from another container"? Specifically, what does "access" mean? Do you want to get the Bundle's handle in order to stop/start/update them? Do you want to import/export packages between the two frameworks? Or do you want to publish/consume services between the two frameworks?